# Textfield not responsive on certain device

Tags: html, css

I have two text fields, they are ok on all devices but when I try the iPhone 5s/5, the text fields drop down a line instead of staying on the same line.

[image: Current appearance]

And I want them like this

[image: Desired appearance]

```css
add .code {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="add-content">
  <div>
    <ion-item class="code">
      <ion-input type="text" maxlength="4"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>a
    <span class="dash">-</span>
    <ion-item class="code">
      <ion-input type="text" maxlength="4"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <input hidden #loseFocus>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the full code including the HTML?

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: At a glance, it looks like your container is too small to fit all three things on a single line. Your options are likely: either making the contents responsive to the parent size, or making sure the parent is a minimum of the size of its children.

Comment: reduce the max-width to 100px on mobile in mediaQuery, it will work for sure, for Iphone 5, resolution is 320px only, and I am sure in this case your textArea is bigger to fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `px` for width use `em, % or VW,` that will make it responsive.

Example:

```
add .code {               
  display: inline-block;                   
  width: 10%;                      
  max-width: 30%;                     
}
```

Using `px` it fixed the width of element that's why it is shifting.

Answer (score 0):

you set your text field using flex.

```css
* {
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.flex-container .code {
   flex: 1 0 auto;
   max-width: 300px;
}

.flex-container .code input {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}


.add-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="add-content">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="code">
      <input type="text" maxlength="4" />
    </div>
    <span class="dash">-</span>
    <div class="code">
      <input type="text" maxlength="4" />
    </div>
    <input hidden #loseFocus>
  </div>
  <button>button</button>
</div>
```

> Note: here I replace `ion-item` with `div`

Comment: Could you tell me how to center them to be on top of the button ?
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzeEo.png

Comment: What you mean by that @EyTA

Comment: I want it to be centred, as you look at it it's not centred, but a little bit on the left

Answer (score -1):

You can try with CSS fixed-width property